# Combinatorics - Choosing a group of 10 out of 2 groups

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have 26 boys and 62 girls and we'd like to know in how many ways we can choose a group of 10 out of them where **at least** 2 boys are in this group.

What I did is I took the total number of combinations for this group:

${88 \choose 10}$

Later, I subtracted the total number of combinations where 10 girls were picked and the total number of combinations that 9 girls were picked:

${88 \choose 10} - {62 \choose 10} - {62 \choose 9}$

Is this the right answer? Because I'm kinda feeling confused since I could also solve it like this:

First I'll choose 2 boys out of a group of 26:
${26 \choose 2}$

For each of this combinations, we need to pick 8 more members:

${26 \choose 2} \cdot {86 \choose 8}$

But I somehow get different results.

Can anyone please explain me what's true and why?

Thanks alot!!

Comment: The first analysis  is correct, but there is a detail that is not quite right. For $9$ girls picked, remember we then need a boy, so there are $\binom{62}{9}\binom{26}{1}$ ways to pick a group of $10$ with exactly $9$ girls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first answer is almost right.  You're subtracting the cases of $0$ and $1$ boy from all possible combinations.  For $0$ boys you have to choose $10$ females so there are $\binom{62}{10}$.  For $1$ boy you have to choose $9$ females **and 1 male** so the correct count is $\binom{62}{9}\cdot\binom{26}{1}$.

Your second answer isn't correct since it regards the $2$ boys you chose in the $\binom{26}{2}$ term as special.  If you have boys $A,B,C$ with $7$ girls your second answer regards first choosing $A,B$ then $7$ girls and $C$ different than first choosing $A,C$ then the same 7 girls with $B$ for example.

Comment: Can you please elaborate some more about why the second answer isn't correct? I'm this close to understanding it.

Comment: Sure.  When you multiply $\binom{26}{2}\cdot \binom{86}{8}$ you are saying "pick out two boys, **then** from the leftover pick out 8 more people".  You are counting pairs $(X,Y)$ where $X$ is a size two subset of the boys, and $Y$ is a size $8$ subset of everyone where $X$ is not a subset of $Y$.  Here are two such distinct pairs: $(\{b_1,b_2\},\{b_3,g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4,g_5,g_6,g_7\})$ and $(\{b_3,b_1\},\{b_2,g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4,g_5,g_6,g_7\})$.  Your solution treats these as distinct outcomes, but really both contain the same set of people.

Comment: No problem  :) !

Answer (score 0):

Here total ways are ${26\choose 2}.{62 \choose 8}+{26 \choose 3}{62\choose 7}.....+{26 \choose 10}{62\choose 0}$ as its atleast 2 so we can have $2,3,4,...10$ in the group hope its clear.Its just another way but your first analysis is right.